# Solidity - How to send ETH from my wallet to another address

Tags: solidity, wallet-transfer

I would like to programmatically send my ETH to another wallet address using Solidity.
Could you please tell me this is possile? If yes, please give me some examples.
I read the docs and it has only for created tokens.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would love to be wrong, but it is not <s>yet</s> possible to send ether from one wallet address to another wallet address using **only** Solidity.

But still, if you want you can write your contract with some method:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Example {
    function sendEther(address _addr) public payable {
        _addr.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

and then using this method send some ether to desired address:

```
await instance.sendEther.sendTransaction(accounts[1], { from: accounts[0], value: 10**18 });
```

But it is not convinient, when you can just use:

```
await web3.eth.sendTransaction({ from: accounts[0], to: accounts[1], value: 10**18 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I use web3, could I connect to my account via web3 and send my eth from it? If yes, could you please tell me how?

Comment: You can use [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/#how-it-works). It will automatically prompt you to "sign" transaction when you trigger `web3.eth.sendTransaction`. Another way is to use [`web3.eth.sendRawTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction). I suggest you to try this functionality on testnet before using it on the mainnet.

Comment: @RomanFrolov can we use the above contract to send eth from other wallet?

Comment: its giving `Uncaught Error: sender account not recognized` if i do so

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil are you using unlocked account? It seems that sender account is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible from a smart contract to an other address.
To do that, you just need the following:

```
sender_address.send(value)
```

You can find some examples [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html#simple-open-auction) (ctrl + f => '.send(' )

Of course, the smart contract needs to own Ether.